# Flink taskmanagers over NAT

Tags: apache-flink, nat

I am trying to run Flink cluster over NAT, where the advertised ports will be different from binding ports.

Is there any support for this in Flink?

I looked through the configuration and source code but did not notice anything hinting to NAT being supported. If not, what is the recommended way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to connect to a Flink component over NAT.

If the component behind NAT is the `JobManager`, then you have to configure `jobmanager.rpc.address` and `jobmanager.rpc.port` with the values of your logical name and port over which the `JobManager` is reachable from the outside network.

If the component behind NAT is the `TaskManager`, then you have to configure `taskmanager.host` and `taskmanager.rpc.port` with the values of your logical name and port over which the `TaskManager` is reachable from the outside network.

## Update

At the moment, it is not possible to run Flink over NAT because of [FLINK-15911](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15911). The problem is that Flink does not offer separate bind and external port configurations and that the `TaskManager` tries to resolve `taskmanager.host` which is not always possible.

Comment: The component in my case is TaskManager, and the issue is - after specifying taskmanager.host - that's the host it tries to actually bind to, while that host is only visible from outside and means nothing from inside the network. Same with port, the external port is forwarded to a different internal port, while TM seems to only allow specifying one port.

Comment: You are right @bezmax. At the moment, the `TaskManager` side seems to be broken because we try to resolve the hostname into an `InetAddress`. Moreover, we don't allow to specify separate bind and external ports. I've created a JIRA ticket to fix the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15911

Comment: Thanks! For now we found a really dirty hack of modifying `/etc/hosts` to have external hostname pointing to localhost. This means that providing external hostname makes flink bind to localhost but also makes it advertize the actual external hostname. Don't think I can do anything like that with ports, so for now will just have 1-to-1 port mapping I guess.